# Error with payment module in Prestashop

Tags: php, oop, module, prestashop

I have installed a payment module for Prestashop. And have this error: ***Cannot redeclare class PaymentModuleCore***. I see what, I try to redeclare extend Class in 26nd line, but I don't know how to fix this. Please help me... Thank you for understanding!

```
<?php

     /*
     *  AirPay - Payment System
     *  Contact: Vitaliy Andrianov <v@airpay.lv>; www.airpay.lv
     *  Version: 1.2
     *  Date: 23.05.2012
     *  Updated: 23.05.2012
     */

     require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/airpay.class.php');

     /*  For debugging */
     if (!(defined('AIRPAY_DEBUG') && AIRPAY_DEBUG == true) || !isset($_fpp))
     {
            class fpp_airpay
            {
                public function log() { }
                public function info() { }
                public function warn() { }
            }

        $_fpp = new fpp_airpay();
     }

     class AIRPAY extends PaymentModuleCore
     {

        private $_html = '';
        private $_postErrors = array();

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->name = 'airpay';
            $this->tab = 'payments_gateways';
            $this->version = '1.0.0';

            parent::__construct();

            /* The parent construct is required for translations */
            $this->page = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
            $this->displayName = $this->l('AirPay');
            $this->description = $this->l('Accepts payments by AirPay');
            $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to delete your details?');

            $config = Configuration::getMultiple(array('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID', 'AIRPAY_SECRETKEY'));
            if (isset($config['AIRPAY_MERCHANTID']))
            {
                $this->merchantid = $config['AIRPAY_MERCHANTID'];
            }
            if (isset($config['AIRPAY_SECRETKEY']))
            {
                $this->secretkey = $config['AIRPAY_SECRETKEY'];
            }
            if (!isset($this->merchantid) OR !isset($this->secretkey))
            {
                $this->warning = $this->l('Merchant ID and secret key must be configured in order to use this module correctly');
            }
        }

        public function install()
        {
            /* This is for logging payment selection events */
            $query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'airpay_orders` (
                  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                  `order_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL default \'\',
                  `rel_order_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL default \'\' COMMENT \'order_num\',
                  `email` varchar(70) NOT NULL default \'\',
                  `amount` int(10) default \'0\',
                  `currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL default \'EUR\',
                  `date` datetime default \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\',
                  `statuss` varchar(25) default NULL,
                  `ip` varchar(15) default NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
                  KEY `email` (`email`),
                  KEY `started` (`date`),
                  KEY `result` (`statuss`),
                  KEY `currency` (`currency`),
                  KEY `rel_order_id` (`rel_order_id`),
                  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';

            //Check version for prestashop 1.4
            $version_mask = explode('.', _PS_VERSION_, 3);
            $version_test = $version_mask[0] == 1 && $version_mask[1] == 4;
            if (!$version_test)
                return false;

            if (!parent::install() OR !Db::getInstance()->Execute($query)
                OR !Configuration::updateValue('AIRPAY_CURRENCY', 'customer')
            OR !Configuration::updateValue('AIRPAY_SANDBOX', 'sandbox')
                OR !$this->registerHook('payment'))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function uninstall()
        {
            if (!Configuration::deleteByName('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID') OR !Configuration::deleteByName('AIRPAY_SECRETKEY')
                OR !Configuration::deleteByName('AIRPAY_CURRENCY') OR !Configuration::deleteByName('AIRPAY_SANDBOX') OR !parent::uninstall())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function getContent()
        {
            $this->_html = '<h2>AirPay</h2>';
            if (isset($_POST['submitAirpay']))
            {
                if (empty($_POST['merchantid']))
                {
                    $this->_postErrors[] = $this->l('AirPay merchant ID is required.');
                }
                if (empty($_POST['secretkey']))
                {
                    $this->_postErrors[] = $this->l('AirPay secret key is required.');
                }
                if (empty($_POST['currency']))
                {
                    $_POST['currency'] = 'customer';
                }
                if (empty($_POST['sandbox']))
                {
                    $_POST['sandbox'] = 'sandbox';
                }
                if (!sizeof($this->_postErrors))
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID', $_POST['merchantid']);
                    Configuration::updateValue('AIRPAY_SECRETKEY', $_POST['secretkey']);
                    Configuration::updateValue('AIRPAY_CURRENCY', $_POST['currency']);
                    Configuration::updateValue('AIRPAY_SANDBOX', $_POST['sandbox']);
                    $this->displayConf();
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->displayErrors();
                }
            }

            $this->displayAirpay();
            $this->displayFormSettings();
            return $this->_html;
        }

        public function displayConf()
        {
            $this->_html .= '
            <div class="conf confirm">
                <img src="../img/admin/ok.gif" alt="'.$this->l('Confirmation').'" />
                '.$this->l('Settings updated').'
            </div>';
        }

        public function displayErrors()
        {
            $nbErrors = sizeof($this->_postErrors);
            $this->_html .= '
            <div class="alert error">
                <h3>'.($nbErrors > 1 ? $this->l('There are') : $this->l('There is')).' '.$nbErrors.' '.($nbErrors > 1 ? $this->l('errors') : $this->l('error')).'</h3>
                <ol>';
            foreach ($this->_postErrors AS $error)
            {
                $this->_html .= '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
            }
            $this->_html .= '
                </ol>
            </div>';
        }

        /* Does the same as mysql_real_escape_string(), only better */
        public function myres($str)
        {
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }

        public function displayAirpay()
        {
            $this->_html .= '
            <img src="../modules/airpay/airpay.gif" style="float:left; margin-right:15px;" />
            <b>'.$this->l('This module allows you to accept payments by AirPay.').'</b><br /><br />
            '.$this->l('If the client chooses this payment mode, your AirPay account will be automatically credited.').'<br />
            '.$this->l('You need to configure your AirPay account first before using this module.').'
            <br /><br /><br />';
        }

        public function displayFormSettings()
        {
            $conf = Configuration::getMultiple(array('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID', 'AIRPAY_CURRENCY', 'AIRPAY_SECRETKEY', 'AIRPAY_SANDBOX'));
            $merchantid = array_key_exists('merchantid', $_POST) ? $_POST['merchantid'] : (array_key_exists('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID', $conf) ? $conf['AIRPAY_MERCHANTID'] : '');
            $secretkey = array_key_exists('secretkey', $_POST) ? $_POST['secretkey'] : (array_key_exists('AIRPAY_SECRETKEY', $conf) ? $conf['AIRPAY_SECRETKEY'] : '');
            $currency = array_key_exists('currency', $_POST) ? $_POST['currency'] : (array_key_exists('AIRPAY_CURRENCY', $conf) ? $conf['AIRPAY_CURRENCY'] : 'prestashop');
            $sandbox = array_key_exists('sandbox', $_POST) ? $_POST['sandbox'] : (array_key_exists('AIRPAY_SANDBOX', $conf) ? $conf['AIRPAY_SANDBOX'] : 'sandbox');

            //$currency_default = new Currency(intval( Configuration::get('PS_CURRENCY_DEFAULT') ))->iso_code;


            $this->_html .= '
            <form action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">
            <fieldset class="width3">
                <legend><img src="../img/admin/contact.gif" />'.$this->l('Settings').'</legend>
                <label for="airpay_merchantid">'.$this->l('AirPay merchant ID').'</label>
                <div class="margin-form"><input type="text" size="33" name="merchantid" id="airpay_merchantid" value="'.htmlentities($merchantid, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'" /></div>
                <label for="airpay_secretkey">'.$this->l('AirPay secret key ').'</label>
                <div class="margin-form"><input type="password" size="33" name="secretkey" id="airpay_secretkey" value="'.htmlentities($secretkey, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'" /></div>

                <label>'.$this->l('Currency').'</label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="radio" name="currency" id="airpay_currency1" value="prestashop" '.($currency == 'prestashop' ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' /> '.
                    '<label style="float: none; font-weight: normal;" for="airpay_currency1">'.$this->l('Use PrestaShop default currency').' (<b>'.$currency_default.'</b>)</label>
                    <br /><input type="radio" name="currency" id="airpay_currency2" value="customer" '.($currency == 'customer' ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' /> '.
                    '<label style="float: none; font-weight: normal;" for="airpay_currency2">'.$this->l('Use customer selected currency').'</label>
                </div>

                <label>'.$this->l('Sandbox').'</label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="radio" name="sandbox" id="airpay_sandbox1" value="sandbox" '.($sandbox == 'sandbox' ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' /> '.
                    '<label style="float: none; font-weight: normal;" for="airpay_sandbox1">'.$this->l('Use TEST mode - fake AirPay transactions)').'</label>
                    <br /><input type="radio" name="sandbox" id="airpay_sandbox2" value="live" '.($sandbox == 'live' ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' /> '.
                    '<label style="float: none; font-weight: normal;" for="airpay_sandbox2">'.$this->l('Use LIVE mode - Real AirPay transactions').'</label>
                </div>

                <br /><center><input type="submit" name="submitAirpay" value="'.$this->l('Update settings').'" class="button" /></center>
            </fieldset>
            </form><br /><br />
            <fieldset class="width3">
                <legend><img src="../img/admin/warning.gif" />'.$this->l('Information').'</legend>'
                .$this->l('In order to use this module, you need to complete the following steps:').'<ol><li>'
                .$this->l('Register as a merchant with').' <a href="http://www.airpay.lv/" target="_blank" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">www.airpay.lv</a>'
                .'</li><li>'
                .$this->l('Recieve your merchant ID, choose a secret key and fill in the fields above').'</li><li>'
                .$this->l('Send an email to').' <a href="mailto:welcome@airpay.lv?subject=PrestaShop%20module" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">welcome@airpay.lv</a> '
                .$this->l('with this data:').'<br /><br />'
                .'<strong>RETURN_URL</strong>: '.(Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') ? 'https://' : 'http://').htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/airpay/return.php<br />'
                .'<strong>STATUS_URL</strong>: '.(Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') ? 'https://' : 'http://').htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/airpay/confirm.php<br /><br />'
                .'</li></ol>'
                .$this->l('If there are any questions, you\'re welcome to contact AirPay by email')
                .' (<a href="mailto:welcome@airpay.lv?subject=PrestaShop%20module" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">welcome@airpay.lv</a>) '
                .'</fieldset>'.$this->getActivities();
        }

        /* Queries the DB for AirPay module log entries and formats the results */
        public function getActivities($start = 0, $limit = 101)
        {
            $total = DB::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'airpay_orders`;');
            $total = intval($total[0]['COUNT(*)']);
            // Don't display anything if there are no log entries
            if ($total == 0)
            {
                return '';
            }
            $query = 'SELECT *, (amount*0.01) as amount FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'airpay_orders` ORDER BY `'._DB_PREFIX_."airpay_orders`.`id` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit;";
            $entries = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query);
            global $smarty;
            $smarty->assign(array(
                'entries' => $entries,
                // This belongs in the presentation layer, but Smarty doesn't make it easy to define it there
                'codes' => array('SUCCESS' => 'green', 'ERROR' => 'red'),
                'total_count' => $total,
                'current_count' => count($entries),
            ));
            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'log.tpl');
        }

        public function hookPayment($params)
        {
            global $smarty, $_fpp;
            $address = new Address(intval($params['cart']->id_address_invoice));
            $customer = new Customer(intval($params['cart']->id_customer));
            $merchantid = Configuration::get('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID');

        $currency_cart = new Currency(intval( $params['cart']->id_currency ));

            if (Configuration::get('AIRPAY_CURRENCY') == 'customer')
            {
                $id_currency = intval($params['cart']->id_currency);
            $no_convert = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $id_currency = intval(Configuration::get('PS_CURRENCY_DEFAULT'));
            $no_convert = false;
            }

            $currency = new Currency(intval($id_currency));

            if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($address) OR !Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)
                OR !Validate::isLoadedObject($currency))
            {
                return $this->l('AirPay error: (invalid address or customer)');
            }

            $products = $params['cart']->getProducts();
            $product_names = array();

            foreach ($products as $key => $product)
            {
                $products[$key]['name'] = str_replace('"', '\'', $product['name']);
                if (isset($product['attributes']))
                    $products[$key]['attributes'] = str_replace('"', '\'', $product['attributes']);
                $products[$key]['name'] = htmlspecialchars($product['name']);
                $amount = number_format(Tools::convertPrice($product['price_wt'], $currency), 2, '.', '');
                $products[$key]['airpayAmount'] = $amount;
                $product_names[] = $products[$key]['name'].' ('.$products[$key]['cart_quantity'].'x)';
            }
            $product_names = join(', ', $product_names);
            if (strlen($product_names) > 255)
            {
                $product_names = substr($product_names, 0, 245).'&hellip;';
            }
            $cart_id = $params['cart']->id;

            $order_id = date('ymdHi').$cart_id.rand(1000,9999);

        if (!$no_convert)       $total = Tools::convertPrice($params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3), $currency_cart, false) / 0.01;
        else            $total = $params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3) / 0.01;

            $smarty->assign(array(
                'address' => $address,
                'country' => new Country(intval($address->id_country)),
                'customer' => $customer,
                'currency' => $currency,
                'm_cart_id' => $cart_id,
                'airpayUrl' => __PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/airpay/order.php',
                'product_name' => $product_names,
                'total' => $total,
                'id_order' => $order_id,
            'description' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
            'hash' => md5(Configuration::get('AIRPAY_SECRETKEY').$order_id.$total.Configuration::get('AIRPAY_MERCHANTID').$currency->iso_code)
            ));

            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'airpay.tpl');
        }

        /* Updates the AirPay module payment status log */
        public function logOrder($order_id, $cart_id, $email, $total, $currency, $status, $ip=NULL)
        {
            global $_fpp;
            if (!isset($ip))
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $query = 'INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'airpay_orders` '
                ."VALUES (NULL, '".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."', '"
                .mysql_real_escape_string($cart_id)."', '"
                .mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($total)."',"
                ."'".mysql_real_escape_string($currency)."', NOW(), '$status', '$ip');";
            $result = Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);
            if (!$result)
            {
                $_fpp->warn($query, 'Query failed');
            }
            else
            {
                $_fpp->info($query);
            }
            return $result;
        }

        public function getOrderDetails($order_id)
        {
            global $_fpp;
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `%sairpay_orders` WHERE order_id = '%s' AND statuss = 'ORDER';",
                _DB_PREFIX_, $this->myres($order_id));
            $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query);
            return empty($results) ? false : $results[0];
        }

        public function getCompletedOrder($order_id)
        {
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `%sairpay_orders` WHERE order_id = '%s' AND statuss = 'SUCCESS' ORDER BY `id` DESC;",
                _DB_PREFIX_, $this->myres($order_id));
            $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query);
            return empty($results) ? false : $results[0];
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 26 should read:

```
 class AIRPAY extends PaymentModule
 {
   ...
 }
```

That's if you haven't figured it out already.